# How to achieve high availability and load balancing in Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, netflix-zuul, netflix-eureka, netflix

I am creating a two node Kubernetes cluster (1 master and 2 slave nodes) which will host Netflix eureka. Microservices would be created for applications which would register themselves on the Eureka server and would find other microservices to communicate from the service registry of Eureka.I want a scenario such that if any node fails, then how can we achieve high availability in this ? Also , there should be load balancing so that requests get simultaneously directed to other nodes in the cluster.

Can anybody let me know a solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

> I want a scenario such that if any node fails, then how can we achieve high availability in this

Creating a Pod directly is not a recommended approach. Lets say that the node on which the Pod is running crashes, then the Pod is not rescheduled and the service is not accessible.

For HA (High Availability), higher level abstractions like [Deployments](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) should be used. A Deployment will create a ReplicaSet which will have multiple Pods associated with it. So, if a node on which the Pod is running crashes then the ReplicaSet will automatically reschedule the Pod on a healthy node and you will get HA.

> Also , there should be load balancing so that requests get simultaneously directed to other nodes in the cluster.

Create a Service of [type LoadBalancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer) for the Deployment and the incoming requests will be automatically redirected to the Pods on the different nodes. In this case a Load Balancer will be automatically created. And there is charge associated with the Load Balancer.

If you don't want to use a Load Balancer then another approach though which is a bit more complicated and powerful is to use [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/). This will also load balance the requests across multiple nodes.

[Here](https://medium.com/google-cloud/kubernetes-nodeport-vs-loadbalancer-vs-ingress-when-should-i-use-what-922f010849e0) is a nice article explaining the difference between a Load Balancer and Ingress.

All the above queries are addressed directly or indirectly in the K8S documentation [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/home/).

Comment: As per your suggestion ,  I deployed Eureka service and created 2 replica sets for that . But while accessing it using curl or by browser, I see that sometimes both replicas show ' No route to host '. I think we are not able to achieve high availability by this because as per my view , at least one instance should be running . Also , should we deploy zuul on this because I heard that zuul uses Ribbon for load balancing in Eureka ?

Comment: Check if the pods are running `kubectl get deployments deployment-name` and then check the pod logs for any error. Also, if a Service is not accessible there can be a lot of reasons, not to blame simply on HA. Check how to debug the Services here - https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-service/.

Comment: Thanks Praveen for answering . I ran the kubectl get deployments command and it is showing there are both replicas and both are available. But on checking kubectl llogs for eureka-server pods , it is showing error logs ----  2018-10-09 11:46:49.299 ERROR 1 --- [nio-8761-exec-1] c.n.eureka.resources.StatusResource      : Could not determine if the replica is av
ailable

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at com.netflix.eureka.resources.StatusResource.isReplicaAvailable(StatusResource.java:90) .

Comment: The strange thing that is happening is that I am  able to access the eureka server GUI from the individual host (slave systems) but it is reflecting this issue in the logs . Also , I am able to access the GUI from the IP of the individual host machines but not from a central load balancer IP .